# Fragment Activity killed after using Camera

Tags: android

I have android application ,the main activity is fragment activity then one of the fragment takes to another activity that leads to screen that has image views and button with intent to call android camera and set the pictures in those image views.
the problem is when I access the camera many times to take pictures and return back to the activity and set the images.
when i click on the back button to return back to the fragment activity it returns me to the phone home screen .

I hope this will simplify activity flows
fragment activity-->activity--->using camera 
after using camera many times fragment activity is not there any more.

This is the code I am using

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyImages");
imagesFolder.mkdir();
File image = new File(imagesFolder,"incident"+incidentId+"("+1+").jpg");
Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(image);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,fileUri);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You may have used "finish()" by the end of calling the Intent . Post your code , so that it would be easy to picture the issue .

Comment: This is the code i am using to call the camera

Comment: But the weird thing that the activity i am using to call the camera is not crash since I am using "onSaveState" but the fragment activity which is before this one is disappear .this behavior happens only when i am using the camera to take pictures many time ..

Comment: @VIGNESH I am not calling finish at all

Comment: are you changing the orientation? it might cause the activity to restart

Comment: thanks for reply but i already set portrait orientation in manifest but it is the same.